# Fast matrix multiplication of XDX^T for D diagonal

Tags: c++, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Consider fast matrix multiplication of XDX^T for X an n by m matrix, and D an m by m diagonal matrix. Here m>>n (suppose n around 1000, m around 100000). In my application, X is a fixed matrix and values of D can change at every iteration.

What would be a fast way to calculate this? At the moment I am just doing simple multiplication in C++.

EDIT: I should clarify my current procedure, it is not "simple multiplication". In particular, I am columnise multiplying the X by the square root of diagonal entries of D to get A:=XD^{1/2}. Then I am directly calculating A*t(A) (which is the multiplication of an n by m matrix with its transpose).

Thank you.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you'll end up with a *symmetric* n by n matrix B with elements Bi,j = sum(k=1,M) of Xi,k · Xj,k · Dk. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Note that for n around 1000, m around 100000, saving the outer products X_,k · X_,k for k=1,...,m takes up too much memory. Otherwise we could use this to speed up calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that D is diagonal, the you can just do simple multiplication. Hopefully, you are not multiplying the zeros.

Comment: See my edit- already doing what you suggested. I am thinking if there are any faster ways which exploit that X is fixed.